# Code signing on Jenkins with remote Mac Mini

Tags: ios, macos, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My configuration.

- Jenkins server with the [Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin)
- Mac Mini as a remote build server
- A personal Apple developer account.

Obviously I'm trying to get code signing working on the remote server.

I believe the fact that I have an individual Apple developer account means I cannot issue "permission" for other developers to work on my project and that the node can't just have it's own Apple ID.

Following the plugin instructions I believe the "provisioning profiles" section is correct.

The keychains are apparently not working. At first I uploaded .cert and .p12 files and it errored on upload. Then I uploaded my entire login.keychain which it successfully parsed. I give it the keychain password. I got the "identity" string by stealing it from the "info" section when right clicking on the key in the keychain manager; "iPhone Developer: William Guynes (XXXXXXXXXX)". Past the successful upload I have no way to knowing whether the other two fields are correct. I believe the password desired is the login.keychain password but the field description is a bit vague. I found a partial blurred example of the "identity" string but I'm guessing about where to get it.

This is not a case of my key being my username and Jenkins using "Jenkins" username. When the job is pushed off to the remote it runs as a user with the name of "ci". I can give ci any permissions needed, including directly manipulating its keychains. I haven't gotten that to work but I feel that a workaround hack like this shouldn't be necessary with the plugin in the first place.

Current build output:

```
Console Output

Started by user William Guynes
Building remotely on mini (osx) in workspace /Users/ci/workspace/websocketclient
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://lion.guynes.net/var/git/WebSocketClient.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://lion.guynes.net/var/git/WebSocketClient.git/
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://lion.guynes.net/var/git/WebSocketClient.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 51c15eabd01c443ef6fee24cc755af60f706a4f0 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 51c15eabd01c443ef6fee24cc755af60f706a4f0
 > git rev-list 51c15eabd01c443ef6fee24cc755af60f706a4f0 # timeout=10
[websocketclient] $ /bin/bash /var/folders/54/kvd8ytzd6yl3d2y7zdxf_ygw0000gp/T/hudson2702132375138804077.sh
Executing do/all
Executing do/setup
Executing do/build
=== BUILD TARGET WebSocketClient OF PROJECT WebSocketClient WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Executing do/test
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have spent a full day googling and trying to find an answer. Many links lead back to [this blog post](http://code-dojo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html) but it describes manually copying the provisioning file and moving the keys from "login" to "System." Itdoesn't take into account a remote server. It appears to be a temporary hack to work around the problem that the plugin was designed to resolve in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I could see the provisioning profile being copied into the correct path by the plugin.
I could also see that it copies the login.keychain provided to the workspace/{jobname} root directory.

The ci user needed that login.keychain added to its search path.

- plugin provided keychain
- ci user's keychain
- system keychain

So I altered my build script.

```
system_keychain='/Library/Keychains/System.keychain'
keychain_list=$(security list-keychains)
echo "${keychain_list}" | grep "${KEYCHAIN_PATH}"
ec=$?
if [[ ${ec} -ne 0 ]]
then
   new_keychain_list=(
      ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}
      $(echo "${keychain_list}" | grep -v "${system_keychain}")
   )
   echo "Setting keychains to" ${new_keychain_list[*]}
   security list-keychains -s ${new_keychain_list[*]}
fi
```

If the provided keychain isn't already in the search path then add it to the beginning. The system is always tacked onto the end when setting it so strip it out before performing a set.